# stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document while using if else condition

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Although while running in my comapny network, it was working fine, however in my home network it is throwing exception stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document.
while using isDisplayed, if error msg is displayed it is working fine.however when element is not displayed, it should move to else condition.I tried with try and catch but still not able to figure out.

```
Console Output:
RRRRRRRR  org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
Exception found ::::org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document


Using below code in main, calling

Acti_05CreateNewCust.errorMsgCust(driver) method
//It is capturing the properties of element which displayed when error will display. 

try     
{
    if(Acti_05CreateNewCust.errorMsgCust(driver).isDisplayed())
        {
            takeSnapShot(driver, "WarnOmCustomerCreation Page");
            if(Acti_05CreateNewCust.click_BtnCancel(driver).isEnabled())
            {
            Acti_05CreateNewCust.click_BtnCancel(driver).click();
            }
            Acti_05CreateNewCust.close_popup(driver);
            Log.warn("Customer has not been created successfully");
            }
}
catch(Exception e)
{

    if(Acti_04ProjandCust.val_newcustomer(driver, ExcelUtils.getCellData(i,0))==true)
    {
        Log.info("Customer has been created successfully");
    }
System.out.println("Exception found ::::"+e);
}


//Acti_05CreateNewCust.errorMsgCust(driver) 

public static WebElement errorMsgCust(WebDriver driver)
     {
        try
        {
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
            element =driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='customerLightBox_footer']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/span"));
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
            Log.warn("Error message element has been identifeid");

        }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
            System.out.println("RRRRRRRR  "+e);
         }
        return element;
     }
```

Comment: where is the else condition?

Comment: Don't know if this is the problem but in `errorMsgCust` you are waiting `element` to be visible when it might be null. Better to do something like `element =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("...")));`

Comment: @pArAs
I used it as:
if(Acti_05CreateNewCust.errorMsgCust(driver).isDisplayed())
 {
 takeSnapShot(driver, "WarnOmCustomerCreation Page");
 if(Acti_05CreateNewCust.click_BtnCancel(driver).isEnabled())
 {
  Acti_05CreateNewCust.click_BtnCancel(driver).click();
 }
  Acti_05CreateNewCust.close_popup(driver);
  Log.warn("Customer has not been created successfully");
 }

 else
 {
 if(Acti_04ProjandCust.val_newcustomer(driver, ExcelUtils.getCellData(i,0))==true)
  {
  Log.info("Customer has been created successfully");
 }

}

It is not wroking so I tried with try and put else in catch

Comment: @guy
I tried with the same, but is getting the same "stale element reference:" exception.
through try catch I tried to handle it, but didn't sucessed.
if it is NULL, it would have thrown different exception.

Comment: seems like element is getting removed from the `DOM` try finding the element again. You can put a catch block `Catch(StaleElementException e)` and then try locating the element again.

Comment: @pArAs
Yes it is happening in the same way, however here we can see I am try to validate the scenario where error msg will display, and when it is getting displayed, it is working fine.

Comment: @pArAs my main requirement that either it should return true or false based on "isDispalyed". this stale exception I am facing almost 90% time of execution.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try below

```
public static WebElement errorMsgCust(WebDriver driver)
{
   try
   {
      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='customerLightBox_footer']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/span")));

   }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       System.out.println("RRRRRRRR  "+e);
    }

   return driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='customerLightBox_footer']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/span"));
}
```

please provide full exception to get more info..

Thank You,
Murali